# Vertical center text within content property of pseudo-element after

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to center vertical a text within the `content` property of my `pseudo-element` `after`. I searched for some answers and found the properties `vertical-align: baseline;` and `display: inline-block;`, but it didn't work. I also tried `vertical-align: middle;` and `vertical-align: -50%` in conbination with `display: block;` (also from other answers) but can't figure out why it doesn't work. At the moment my `"!"` is on the bottom and not centered vertical as I expected. Any ideas?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #93B8C2;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "!";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #DD3322;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 25px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Solved it by my own: Solution below.

Answer (score 1):

**Found my own answer:** I solved it with flexbox properties `display: flex;`, `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` to solve this vertical alignment problem for pseuo-element. I also can remove the `text-align` and `vertical-align` properties.

**Solution below:**

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #93B8C2;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "!";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #DD3322;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 25px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```